# Monotone function in a subset

Tags: calculus

Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be continues and non constant function such that $f''$ exists $\forall x \in (a,b)$. Show that there is a $(c,d) \subset (a,b)$ where $f$ is monotone.

This is an exersice for preparation in a mathematical competition. I tried to construct this (c,d) by sharing (a,b) in n parts, i also took cases for $f''$ (if it is positive, negative) but i don't think that is the right way. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

1. $f'$ is continuous
2. Since $f$ is not constant, $f'$ is not identically zero.
3. $f'^{-1}((-\infty, 0))$ and $f'^{-1}((0, \infty))$ are open.
4. Conclude the result.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $f$ is non-constant and hence the derivative $f'$ takes a non-zero value at some interior point, say $\xi$, in interval $(a, b) $. Since $f''$ exists, the derivative $f'$ is continuous and hence maintains its sign in a small open interval, say $(c, d) $, containing $\xi$. Thus $f$ is monotone in $[c, d] $.

One can see that the existence of $f''$ is not really needed, but rather only the continuity of $f'$ is the key here.